# Eclipselink Lazy loading failing in glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish, eclipselink, lazy-loading

We are migrating our application servers from weblogic10c to glassfish 5.

One of the applications is failing to fetch a collection in an object with below error.

This whole application was working fine in Weblogic but seeing issues with glassfish. Is there a configuration that needs to be done to enable Eclipselink or Lazyloading in the glassfish?

```
[2018-12-03T14:45:47.606-0600] [glassfish 5.0] [FATAL] [] 
[javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] [tid: _ThreadID=37 
_ThreadName=http-listener-2(5)] [timeMillis: 1543869947606] [levelValue: 
1100] [[
  /protected/sv_request.xhtml @13,246 value="Notes (# 
{userManagedBean.noteCount})": Exception [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse 
Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using 
indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with 
an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that relationship is 
traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY 
relationship prior to serialization.
javax.el.ELException: /protected/sv_request.xhtml @13,246 value="Notes (# 
{userManagedBean.noteCount})": Exception [EclipseLink-7242] (Eclipse 
Persistence Services - 2.7.0.v20170811-d680af5): 
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: An attempt was made to traverse a relationship using 
indirection that had a null Session.  This often occurs when an entity with 
an uninstantiated LAZY relationship is serialized and that relationship is 
traversed after serialization.  To avoid this issue, instantiate the LAZY 
relationship prior to serialization.
at
```

com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:119)
    at

javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:200)
    at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:187)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.getValue(UICommand.java:227)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeMarkup(CommandButtonRenderer.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandbutton.CommandButtonRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandButtonRenderer.java:49)

**This is button on our xhtml view**

```
 <p:commandButton id="selectButton" action="#{userManagedBean.editRequest}" 
icon="ui-icon-search" title="View">  
 <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{row}" target=" 
 {userManagedBean.selectedRequest}" />  
 </p:commandButton>
```

This command button passes the selected requested object to the usermanaged bean.

**Managed bean in web app**

```
import prepay.dsl.persistance.Request;
@ManagedBean(name = "userManagedBean")
@SessionScoped
public class UserManagedBean extends AbstractManagedBean implements 
Serializable {
private Request request;

public Request getSelectedRequest() {
    return request;
}

public void setSelectedRequest(Request selectedRequest) {
    setSelectedRequest(selectedRequest.getRequestId());
}

public String getNoteCount() {
    return String.valueOf(request.getNoteCollection() == null ? 0 : request.getNoteCollection().size());
}

public void setSelectedRequest(Integer requestPK) {
    this.request = getPrePayFacadeRemote().getRequestByPk(requestPK);
    this.approveErrorMessage = null;
    this.bypassValue = new BypassValue();
    this.emailUnknown = Request.UNKNOWN_CARRIER_EMAIL.equals(request.getVendorContactEmail());
    this.selectedVendor = new Vendor(this.request.getVendorId(), this.request.getVendorName(), null, null);
    this.currentVendors.add(selectedVendor);
}
```

The setSelectedRequest in the above bean calls the ejb to get the data.

**DSL EJB**

```
@Stateless(mappedName = "ejb/PrePayFacade")
@Remote
public class PrePayFacadeBean implements PrePayFacadeRemote {
 public Request getRequestByPk(Integer requestId) {
    if (LOGGER.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOGGER.debug(String.format("Getting request id [%d]", requestId));
    }
    entityManager.flush();
    Request request = entityManager.find(Request.class, requestId);
    // Trigger full population
    request.getAttachmentCollection();
    request.getAuditHistoryCollection();
    request.getNoteCollection();
    return request;
}
}
```

The getRequestByPk method gets the data from the db and also populate the note collection. But still I see a failure when fetching this Lazy collection.

**This is our Request object**

```
@Entity
public class Request implements Serializable {
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "request", fetch = 
FetchType.LAZY)
@OrderBy(value = "noteDatetime DESC")
private Collection<Note> noteCollection;
.
.
.
}
```

**persistenxe.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
 <persistence-unit name="prepayDS" transaction-type="JTA">
  <jta-data-source>jdbc/EnterpriseDS</jta-data-source>
  <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

 </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I don't know why this would be different in Glassfish from WebLogic, but I suspect that maybe your EJB wasn't really remote or serializing as it might now be doing in Glassfish. The "// Trigger full population" comment looks like it is trying to pre-load the getNoteCollection() list, but this isn't actually doing anything with the returned Collection that would cause it to be triggered or loaded from the database. Try calling size() or something on the collection to fetch it.

Comment: Thanks, using size() worked.